# on canopy we are trying to find out how to change an image. specifically a .png file

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am in a class right now in high school and we are trying to understand how to be able to add a border, change colors, and things of this caliber. we are unable to find exactly what we are looking for in our searches. Do you think you could help us, or at least by leading us in the right direction?

If I need to be more specific, I would like to understand on how to change the mask around the image to use the negative space to create a border instead of having to go over the actual image itself.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: This is a python question, and more specifically a question about the Python Image Library (current version is named Pillow: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.3.x/handbook/overview.html). I am retagging this question accordingly (python, pillow). Even though the pillow package is provided by canopy, and even though you run your program with Canopy's ipython, it's neither a canopy nor an ipython question.